# How do I add a DOM node to a Panel in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to embedd legacy javascript code in an ExtJS application. Our application will use ExtJS dialogs to display old javasccript forms (before we eventually get round to redoing them in ExtJS).

I am trying to add a DOM node to an **Ext.Panel** (or **Ext.window.Window** for that matter). Not sure if its possible or what methods there are. I need some kind of **appendChild** method like below :

```
var mainPanel = document.create('div');

mainPanel.appendChild(getVeryComplicatedLegacyHTML())


var p =  new Ext.Panel({
     title: 'another panel',
     titleCollapse: true
});

p.appendChild(mainPanel ); //???
```

Is this at all possible in ExtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this at all possible in ExtJS?

there is no magic here... under ext cover the plain old html and css

`Ext.panel.Panel` (any ext components and its descendants) doesn't have `appendChild` method.
Has the `Ext.dom.Element` wrapper of the DOMElement [appendChild method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-appendChild) and any component has its element reference via `el`/[`getEl()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getEl).

Simple example, creates an auxiliary component with your legacy html inside a panel.
When panel is rendered then the legacy html is injected inside the component, using [update()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-update) method (which uses the `this.el.update()` [element method inside](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-update)) :

```
var p = new Ext.Panel({
     title: 'another panel',
     titleCollapse: true,
     items: [
     {
         xtype: 'box',
         itemId: 'fake-cmp'
     }],
     listeners: {
         boxready: function(panel) {
             var fakeCmp = panel.down('#fake-cmp');
             fakeCmp.update(getVeryComplicatedLegacyHTML());
         } 
     }
});
```

[ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#)

Comment: at your 4th line , fakeComponnet.el is undefined. Does this component first need to be added somewhere or rendered somewhere before it contains DOM objects?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer(when panel is rendered the fake component is updated with legacy html). When a component is rendered then its `el` could be used to add/update and etc.

Comment: if i have the line fakeCmp.update(document.createElement('div')); it doesnt render. It just prints out the string [object HTMLDivElement] inside the panel

Comment: yes, please look at docs for `Ext.Component#update` method that in current situation uses undercover the `Ext.dom.Element#update` that accepts the html string as the first argument (I've added links in my answer). You could use `fakeCmp.getEl().appendChild(document.createElement('div'))` to add dom element.

Comment: Another useful `Ext.dom.Element` method is [createChild](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-createChild) e.g. `fakeCmp.el.createChild({tag: 'div', html: 'hello'})` or `fakeCmp.el.createChild(document.createElement('div'))`
Also look at [Ext.DomHelper](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.DomHelper)